# Finding the graph defined by $x = \sin \theta$ and $y = 3 - 2\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

The question is as follows:

> Find the graph of the parametric equations defined by
>
> $$
> x(\theta) = \sin \theta  \\
> y(\theta) = 3 - 2\cos(2\theta)
> $$

We are supposed to use the identity that
$\sin^2\theta \ + \cos^2\theta\ = 1$
However, that identity requires that sin and cos both have the same theta, and in this instance they are different.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2 (\theta) -  \sin^2(\theta)$. Now apply your identity to get rid of the cosine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(\theta) = \sin \theta  \\
y(\theta) = 3 - 2\cos(2\theta)$$

Note that $$ \cos (2\theta) = 1-2\sin ^2 (\theta)$$

The expression for $y(\theta )$ simplifies to $$y(\theta) = 3 - 2\cos(2\theta)=1+4\sin ^2 (\theta) = 1+4 x^2$$

Thus your parabola is simply $y=1+4x^2$ where, $-1\le x\le 1$